# Easy Example of JPA OneToMany in Enterprise and Contacts

Tags: java, database, jpa, javadb

Please i need a Simple example of a JPA Entity denoting Enterpries with Contacts.
Enterprises having many Contacts referenced by rc_No(String);
Look At my code, any problem

```
@Entity
public class Enterprises implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String rcNo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprises", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Contacts> contacts;

public void addContact(Contacts contact) {
    contacts.add(contact);
}

public String getRcNo() {
    return rcNo;
}

public void setRcNo(String rcNo) {
    this.rcNo = rcNo;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}.....
```

Look at the Contacts Entity also

```
@Entity
public class Contacts implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="rcNo")
private Enterprises enterprises;

public Enterprises getEnterprises() {
    return enterprises;
}

public void setEnterprises(Enterprises enterprises) {
    this.enterprises = enterprises;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String fullName;
private String designation;
private String telephoneNo;
private String emailAddress;
.....
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is it giving any issue.

Comment: Yes. It complaining about the Relationship. Thanks But i figured it out. I spend many hours!!!